# Flux Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Flux is not defined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am trying to run a ReactJS + CoffeeScript application locally and the page seems to load in the JS but does not show anything (blank white screen) with an error in the console that says

Uncaught ReferenceError: Flux is not defined

This is the snippet of code where the error seems to be arising from.
We have Flux as part of the Node Modules in the application. I don't see what I am expected to do here.

Please guide.

```
dispatcher = new Flux.Dispatcher();

module.exports = dispatcher;

},{}],5:[function(require,module,exports){
var Auth, LoggedInMixin, isEarlyPage, user;

Auth = require('./auth.coffee');

user = require('./stores/user.coffee');

isEarlyPage = function(path) {
  return path.substr(1, 5) === 'early' || path.substr(1, 8) === 'settings';
};

module.exports = LoggedInMixin = {
  statics: {
    willTransitionTo: function(transition) {
      if (!user.isLoggedIn()) {
        console.error("User not logged in, redirecting.");
        return Auth.redirect(transition);
      }
      if (!user.hasAccess() && !isEarlyPage(transition.path)) {
        console.error("User does not have early access, redirecting.");
        return transition.redirect('early');
      }
    }
  }
};


},{"./auth.coffee":2,"./stores/user.coffee":11}],6:[function(require,module,exports){
var Constants, Nav, dispatcher, stores;

Constants = require('./constants.coffee');

Nav = require('./views/nav.cjsx');

dispatcher = require('./dispatcher.coffee');
```

Comment: The very first line is `dispatcher = new Flux.Dispatcher();`; it looks like `Flux` isn't defined. This looks like a client-side bundle built with browserify or webpack; what does the original file that calls that line look like?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I wasn't requiring 'flux' in my dispatcher file.
Fixed this by simply adding Flux = require 'flux' in my dispatcher.coffee file.

Now facing another issue with the React file that gives me such an error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClass' of undefined

I understand this is a React issue.

Am I expected to say
React = require 'react' 
in every single file?

Comment: `> Am I expected to say React = require 'react' in every single file?`
yes, you are =)